# kafka-stream: Get CorruptRecordException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I wrote a simple kafka-stream program according to this tutorial:
http://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/tutorial

---

### Program

**Pipe.java:**

```
package eric.kafka.stream;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;

/**
 * kafka-stream - pipe,
 */
public class Pipe {
    // topic names,
    public static final String TOPIC_INPUT = "streams-plaintext-input";
    public static final String TOPIC_OUTPUT = "streams-pipe-output";

    public static void pipe() {
        // set up properties,
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-pipe"); // app id,
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092"); // kafka server,
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass()); // serialization / deserialization class, for key,
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass()); // serialization / deserialization class, for value,

        // create stream - source,
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, String> sourceStream = builder.stream(TOPIC_INPUT); // create stream, with specified input topic,
        sourceStream.to(TOPIC_OUTPUT); // set output topic of stream,

        // print stream info,
        final Topology topology = builder.build();
        System.out.println(topology.describe());

        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // attach shutdown handler,
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() { // trigger by ctrl+c,
                streams.close(); // close stream,
                latch.countDown(); // trigger latch, so that jvm will terminate,
            }
        });

        try {
            streams.start(); // start kafka,
            latch.await(); // keep jvm running,
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pipe();
    }
}
```

---

### Testing steps

Here are the steps that I start zookeeper & kafka & the program:

```
* create a maven project, if not yet,
* add dependency - via maven,
    e.g
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
* add exec maven plugin,
    e.g
          <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
          </plugin>
* 
* [stream program - pipe]
* create a class Pipe.java,
    * create a method test(),
    * call test() within main(),
    * 
* 
* cd $KAFKA_HOME
* 
* [start server]
* start zookeeper,
    command:
        bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
* start kafka server,
    command:
        bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
* 
* [create topic]
* create topic,
    command:
        # topic - input,
        bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic streams-plaintext-input

        # topic - output,
        bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic streams-pipe-output --config cleanup.policy=compact
* list topic,
    command:
        bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
* 
* [start streaming application]
* start Pipe program,
    command:
        mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=eric.kafka.stream.Pipe
* 
* [start producer & consumer]
* start a producer, to create input,
    command:
        bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic streams-plaintext-input
* start a consumer, to read output,
    command:
        bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic streams-pipe-output --from-beginning
* 
* [input a line]
* in producer console,                      TODO ... get error here ...
    input line:
        Hello, how are you?
* in consumer console,
    will see output same as input,
*
```

---

### Error output

After starting the Pipe program, I connect it via producer, and input a line, then get following error:

```
[2018-03-06 04:31:23.281] INFO  [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.info() - 351]: stream-thread [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] partition assignment took 24 ms.
    current active tasks: [0_0]
    current standby tasks: []
    previous active tasks: []

[2018-03-06 04:31:23.349] INFO  [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.info() - 346]: stream-thread [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
[2018-03-06 04:31:23.350] INFO  [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.info() - 346]: stream-client [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3]State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
[2018-03-06 04:31:50.063] WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.warn() - 251]: [Producer clientId=streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 3 on topic-partition streams-pipe-output-0, retrying (9 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE
[2018-03-06 04:31:50.165] WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.warn() - 251]: [Producer clientId=streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 4 on topic-partition streams-pipe-output-0, retrying (8 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE
[2018-03-06 04:31:50.267] WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.warn() - 251]: [Producer clientId=streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 5 on topic-partition streams-pipe-output-0, retrying (7 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE
[2018-03-06 04:31:50.369] WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.warn() - 251]: [Producer clientId=streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 6 on topic-partition streams-pipe-output-0, retrying (6 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE
[2018-03-06 04:31:50.471] WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.warn() - 251]: [Producer clientId=streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 7 on topic-partition streams-pipe-output-0, retrying (5 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE
[2018-03-06 04:31:50.573] WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.warn() - 251]: [Producer clientId=streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 8 on topic-partition streams-pipe-output-0, retrying (4 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE
[2018-03-06 04:31:50.675] WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.warn() - 251]: [Producer clientId=streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 9 on topic-partition streams-pipe-output-0, retrying (3 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE
[2018-03-06 04:31:50.777] WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.warn() - 251]: [Producer clientId=streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 10 on topic-partition streams-pipe-output-0, retrying (2 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE
[2018-03-06 04:31:50.879] WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.warn() - 251]: [Producer clientId=streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 11 on topic-partition streams-pipe-output-0, retrying (1 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE
[2018-03-06 04:31:50.981] WARN  [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.warn() - 251]: [Producer clientId=streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 12 on topic-partition streams-pipe-output-0, retrying (0 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE
[2018-03-06 04:31:51.085] ERROR [kafka-producer-network-thread | streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.error() - 301]: task [0_0] Error sending record (key null value hello timestamp 1520281908878) to topic streams-pipe-output due to {}; No more records will be sent and no more offsets will be recorded for this task.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.CorruptRecordException: This message has failed its CRC checksum, exceeds the valid size, or is otherwise corrupt.
[2018-03-06 04:31:53.265] ERROR [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AssignedTasks.error() - 301]: stream-thread [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] Failed to commit stream task 0_0 due to the following error:
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [0_0] Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record (key null value hello timestamp 1520281908878) to topic streams-pipe-output due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.CorruptRecordException: This message has failed its CRC checksum, exceeds the valid size, or is otherwise corrupt..
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl$1.onCompletion(RecordCollectorImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:627)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:596)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:557)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.handleProduceResponse(Sender.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.access$100(Sender.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender$1.onComplete(Sender.java:692)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:482)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:474)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.CorruptRecordException: This message has failed its CRC checksum, exceeds the valid size, or is otherwise corrupt.
[2018-03-06 04:31:53.266] INFO  [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.info() - 346]: stream-thread [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] State transition from RUNNING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN
[2018-03-06 04:31:53.266] INFO  [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.info() - 336]: stream-thread [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
[2018-03-06 04:31:53.268] INFO  [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.info() - 341]: [Producer clientId=streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
[2018-03-06 04:31:53.273] INFO  [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.info() - 346]: stream-thread [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD
[2018-03-06 04:31:53.273] INFO  [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.info() - 346]: stream-client [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3]State transition from RUNNING to ERROR
[2018-03-06 04:31:53.273] WARN  [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.warn() - 236]: stream-client [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3]All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.
[2018-03-06 04:31:53.273] INFO  [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.info() - 336]: stream-thread [streams-pipe-455df74a-b0ca-4612-8df0-c582a6f779b3-StreamThread-1] Shutdown complete
[WARNING] 
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: task [0_0] Abort sending since an error caught with a previous record (key null value hello timestamp 1520281908878) to topic streams-pipe-output due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.CorruptRecordException: This message has failed its CRC checksum, exceeds the valid size, or is otherwise corrupt..
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl$1.onCompletion(RecordCollectorImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:627)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:596)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:557)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.handleProduceResponse(Sender.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.access$100(Sender.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender$1.onComplete(Sender.java:692)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:101)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:482)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:474)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.CorruptRecordException: This message has failed its CRC checksum, exceeds the valid size, or is otherwise corrupt.
```

Above is the console output, I also checked `$KAFKA_HOME/logs/` didn't found any error lines.

---

### Software versions

**OS** is `Linux mint mate 18 (64 bit)`.

Local **Scala** version is `scala-2.12.2`.

Local **Kafka** version is `kafka_2.12-1.0.0`.

**Maven** dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

### Questions

I have run the `demo` from following line on my local, and it works well:
http://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/quickstart

So, seems the setup is ok.

Is it due to the **versions** of maven dependeny ? Since I saw maven dependency `kafka-streams 1.0.0` actually in turn has a dependency for `kafka_2.11 1.0.0`, but **not** `2.12`.

Any help?

Comment: Is this reproducible? The error indicates, that the broker does not accept the write -- it doesn't seem to be client side issue. Does the log revile more information?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I deleted the topics, and start again, the same error would occur.

Comment: Unclear without the logs. I would try to investigate there with DEBUG level enabled. If you can't find anything by yourself, ask for help at user mailing list: https://kafka.apache.org/contact

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Question update, with all the error output that I could found, and more information about the test, not sure is that useful.

Comment: I have no idea atm why the message might get corrupted on write. Kafka Streams code is purely Java based, thus Scala version should not matter. Does the broker log anything?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I checked all dated file in `$KAFKA_HOME/logs`, there are not a single error or warning, the `server.log` also don't have error or warning.

Comment: Sorry. Really have no idea. Maybe ask at user-mailing list: https://kafka.apache.org/contact

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Issue solved, check the answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem in this case is following the [quickstart tutorial](https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation/streams/quickstart) a little too closely. It has you create the output stream like this:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create \
--zookeeper localhost:2181 \
--replication-factor 1 \
--partitions 1 \
--topic streams-wordcount-output \
--config cleanup.policy=compact
```

If you simply change `streams-wordcount-output` to `streams-pipe-output`, the example will break because of `cleanup.policy=compact`. The compact setting enables [log compaction](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction), which requires a key and a value. The simple pipe demo only has a value, so errors like yours show up.

Create the topic like this and it will work:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create \
--zookeeper localhost:2181 \
--replication-factor 1 \
--partitions 1 \
--topic streams-pipe-output
```

You'll also need to run the consumer like this (changing `Long` to `String`):

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
--topic streams-pipe-output \
--from-beginning \
--formatter kafka.tools.DefaultMessageFormatter \
--property print.key=true \
--property print.value=true \
--property key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer \
--property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

This will also help you see the `null` key.

Comment: Simply remove option `--config cleanup.policy=compact` when create topic, fixed the issue.

Comment: Interesting. Side note: in the word-count example, enabling compaction is actually correct as the result is a KTable (note, that for KTables, it's insured that there are no null-keys)

Comment: Great answer!  There *really* needs to be a more informative error from the broker for this.  I churned on it for a while.